# Using ng-class to add CSS3 animations conditionally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, animation

I have a two CSS3 animations I am adding to the dom when particular conditions are satisfied in my controller. I am currently using ng-class to bring in the different animations (shake Y & shake X) when these conditions are satisfied. (I'm just including the relevant js):

```
$scope.submitAnswer = function($index) {
    ...

    if ($index == current) {
        console.log('correct!');
        $scope.shaken = 'shakeY';
    }
    else {
        console.log('incorrect!');
        $scope.shaken = 'shakeX';
    }
}
```

and here's the relevant HTML:

```
    <div 
        id="philosopher" 
        ng-class="shaken"
        ng-click="submitAnswer($index);" 
        ng-repeat="philosopher in philosophers">
        <img ng-src="images/{{philosopher.signifier}}.png" height="142px" width="auto" />
        <h2>{{philosopher.name}}</h2>
    </div>
```

This is working as I wish, **however**, I find that i cant continually apply the same animation class and have the animation execute - I need to alternate (between satisfying the if statement and triggering the else).

I figured out that I could use a custom directive and ngAnimate to trigger the animation repeatedly, but **I do not know how to implement the separate animations based on the outcome of the if else**
This is one of the directives:

```
app.directive('shake', function($animate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            element.bind('click', function() {

                $animate.addClass(element, 'shakeX', function() {
                    $animate.removeClass(element, 'shakeX');
                });

            });
        }
    };
});
```

**How can I continually reapply shakeX and shakeY to ng-class or how can I only use my directive based on the outcome of the if else statement??**

**EDIT**

Finally got it going! Thank you for the help, what ended up working was implementing a timeout function in the if statement in just the right way. (I know technically you shouldnt use functions within if statements [i think thats a rule right?], but I finally got it working!) This is essentially where i ended up:

```
    if ($index == current) {
        console.log('correct!');
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.shaken = 'shakeY'
        })
    }
    else {
        console.log('incorrect!');
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.shaken = 'shakeX'
        })
    }
```

Comment: Can you make the animation repetitive in the CSS itself?

Comment: The idea is to have the animation occur once after each click. Wouldn't doing it in CSS make it just continually repeat regardless of user input?

Comment: Yes, that's true. BUT, knowing the duration of the animation, you can unassign the class after the animation period. Would that work?

Comment: Hmmm. possibly. What would be the best way to do that? Is there a way to do that with angular's syntax? Or do i write a timeout function? The animations are both 0.42s. Thank you for the response by the way.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like it would be the simplest to use angular's $timeout function (similar to setTimeout, but also forces a digest cycle). You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a directive to achieve what you want. The problem is when you're assigning the same value in the scope, the watcher for the scope property isn't triggered if it has the same value. What you need to do is change the value of the scope property from a decoy value or empty value and then use a `$timeout` to change the value from the decoy value to the original one.

Something like this:

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/jinpOeBp9qM5eyYJgNPH?p=preview)**

*HTML*

```
<div ng-class="shake" ng-click="shakeX()">Shake X</div>
<div ng-class="shake" ng-click="shakeY()">Shake Y</div>
```

*JAVASCRIPT*

```
$scope.shakeX = function() {
  $scope.shake = '';
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.shake = 'shakeX';
  })
};

$scope.shakeY = function() {
  $scope.shake = '';
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.shake = 'shakeY';
  })
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the response & work, am checking this out, will let you know if it works!

Comment: Thank you! This works quite well, but i have a question with regards to implementation- How do I make it so that shakeY() is called when the if statement is satisfied in the controller and shakeX() is called when it reverts to the else statement?

Comment: YES! Finally got it going. Thank you man! That timeout function was what did it. Just had to experiment with getting it in the right spot. safe :)

Answer (score 0):

### Direct Class Changing Approach

Judging by our little chat in the comments, sounds like a timeout for the duration of the animation would be the best approach. Basically, you just need to change this:

```
$animate.addClass(element, 'shakeX', function() {
    $animate.removeClass(element, 'shakeX');
});
```

into this:

```
$animate.addClass(element, 'shakeX', function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        $animate.removeClass(element, 'shakeX');
    }, 420);
});
```

And don't forget to add the `$timeout` dependency.

To recap, the idea is to remove the class after the CSS animations are finished so that the class could be reassigned upon the next click.

---

### Controller Scope Variable Approach

Or, if you wish your original approach from the controller, you can do something similar:

```
if ($index == current) {
    console.log('correct!');
    $scope.shaken = 'shakeY';
}
else {
    console.log('incorrect!');
    $scope.shaken = 'shakeX';
}

$timeout(function() {
    $scope.shaken = false;
}, 420);
```

This one just resets the scope variable to false after the animation and it doesn't care which class it was.

---

### `$watch`ing Scope Variable in Linker Approach

And this is how you can do the whole thing from the directive, this should be in the linker function:

```
scope.$watch('shaken', function(newValue, oldValue) {

    if (newValue != 'shakeX' && newValue != 'shakeY')
        return; // just in case

    $animate.addClass(element, newValue, function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            $animate.removeClass(element, newValue);
        }, 420);
    });
});
```

We $watch for the changes of the `shaken` variable, and apply changes accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to write this sort of $animate syntax outside of custom directives? Because the issue with the custom directive in the original post was not repeating the animation, that part worked, what did not work (or what i did not understand) with the custom directive was making that animation work according to the outcome of the 'if else' in the controller. - oh just saw your edit, looking.

Comment: Not sure I fully understood the issue, but if you wish the directive to behave based on the scope variable value, you have to $watch for that variable changes. The if/else part remains the same, you just need to tell the directive when a change occurs since this way you're not binding anything.

Comment: Your second solution here is pretty much exactly what i just tried after talking with you in the comments. I threw a console.log('test') in there to watch it in the console. It does indeed show up 400ms after all my other logs, but the animation still only works once! frustrating.

Comment: It doesn't reassign the class after the next click?

Comment: Okay. This is a part of angular I am not familiar with (as i am new to both it and js in general). I assume $watch goes next to $animate in my directive function? Within the body of the 'if' statement would i put something like $scope.correct = true, and then tell the directive to watch for that?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a watch example and a short description. Same thing with `$scope.correct`, as long as you have three states: idle, incorrect and correct. You can pull if off with a boolean (but be careful, use `===` instead of `==` when checking because undefined is falsy) like: undefined, false and true. You're welcome! :)

Comment: In the example what are newValue and oldValue meant to signify? I think that is the only thing i am unclear on.

Comment: The old and the new value of the scope var. Say you have a scope var `Kevin` and you change it from 1 to 2, the `oldValue` in the $watch callback would be 1 and the `newValue` would be 2. You don't need the `oldValue` in your example.

Comment: I think i understand. This has been very helpful! Unfortunately i still cant get this to work. devtools is telling me that $scope is not defined (in the directive. shouldn't I be using scope rather than $scope?)